# Write a function index -- takes list and a number, and returns the index of the first element with the specified value

Tags: insert

Wouldn't this question need 3 parameters instead of 2, being the list, index, and item being added?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You don't tell us what language you're working in but your function will have 2 parameters: the list and the value looked for, and 1 return type. If it is Java it might be:

```
public static int findIndex(String[] myList, String valueToLookFor) {
int indice;
// calculations here
return indice;
}
```

I believe in some languages you can speak if IN parameters and OUT parameters in which case yes, there are 2 IN parameters plus 1 OUT parameter = 3.